# Severity: Warning --> fopen(./upload/ &lt;table cellspacing=&quot;0&quot;

Tags: php, codeigniter, filenames

I am using file read functionality in one my application.

Sometimes I am getting the exception while opening and closing file because in filename I am getting as HTML string, what do I need to do to protect application or to identify this is not the correct name?

Here is the full stack error.

> ERROR - 2017-02-27 06:28:21 --> Severity: Warning --> fopen(./upload/

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="titleBorderx" width="30">
      <table height="25" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" width="25" bgcolor="black">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="L_default_x" class="x" valign="middle" align="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="titleBorder" id="L_default_2">Network Access Message:<span class="TitleDescription"> The page cannot be displayed</span> </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="spacer">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td></tr></tbody></table>
<table width="400">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="" width="25"></td>
    <td width="400"><span class="explain"><id id="L_default_3"><b>Explanation:</b></id></span><id id="L_default_4"> There is a problem with the page you are trying to reach and it cannot be displayed. </id><br><br>
    <b><span class="tryThings"><id id="L_default_5"><b>Try the following:</b></id></span></b> 
      <ul class="TryList">
        <li id="L_default_6"><b>Refresh page:</b> Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The timeout may have occurred due to Internet congestion.
</li><li id="L_default_7"><b>Check spelling:</b> Check that you typed the Web page address correctly. The address may have been mistyped.
</li><li id="L_default_8"><b>Access from a link:</b> If there is a link to the page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that link.

      </li></ul>
<id id="L_default_9">If you are still not able to view the requested page, try contacting your administrator or Helpdesk.</id> <br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="spacer"><tbody><tr><td height="15"></td></tr></tbody></table>

<table width="400">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="" width="25"></td>
    <td width="400" id="L_default_10"><b>Technical Information (for support personnel)</b> 
      <ul class="adminList">
        <li id="L_default_11">Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your Forefront TMG administrator. (12217)
</li><li id="L_default_12">IP Address: 10.40.0.20
</li><li id="L_default_13">Date: 2/27/2017 6:28:21 AM [GMT]
</li><li id="L_default_14">Server: SYS2019.netsolpk.com
</li><li id="L_default_15">Source: web filter

      </li></ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> ): failed to open stream: File name too long /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/php/public/application/controllers/Readfile.php 159

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter framework of php.

Comment: I changed all `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;` from the error you got... For readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fopen` function has a too long string in it. And I also think this cant be valid. You are looking for a file in `./upload/` with the name:

`&lt;table cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot`...

The name is too long and invalid. I think you pass a variable to the `fopen` function the content of the variable isn't correct.